# C# kestrel https working on windows but not on mac

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, kestrel

I have the following code:

```cs
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
   .UseKestrel()
   .UseUrls("https://*:" + port)
   .Configure(Configure)
   .Build();
```

which works wonderfully on windows - I can access it with https://127.0.0.1:1111 and it works fine.    When I try it on a mac - it runs, but when I try and connect to it, it immediately just goes "connection closed"

I googled and found that in usekestrel, you should be able to add

```cs
   .UseKestrel( options => options.UseHttps...
```

which is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.kestrelserveroptionshttpsextensions.usehttps?view=aspnetcore-1.1):

however when I try it, I'm only finding .UseSystemd as an option - no .useHttps - even though I'm referencing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.

What am I doing wrong?  Why does it behave differently on mac vs windows, and how do I fix it so that it also works on the mac?

Comment: Would help if you specified what version of .NET Core you are using...

Comment: oh.. didn't realise that would change things.    It's netcoreapp3.1

Comment: And if you go to the page you linked for ASP.NET Core 3.1, you get a message stating "The requested page is not available for ASP.NET Core 3.1." Which means that API has been removed (it was only available in 1.0 and 1.1 from what I can see). Which means that you should be careful following arbitrary advice from Google.

Comment: Documentation is Core 1.1 about

Comment: Try localhost instead of 127.0.0.1.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.endpointaddress?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: so I've found the 3.1 equivalent - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.listenoptionshttpsextensions.usehttps?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions_UseHttps_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Server_Kestrel_Core_ListenOptions_ - and tried .ConfigureKestrel( serveroptions => serveroptions.listen( ipaddress.any, port, listenoptions => listoptions.UseHttps() ))).  -  with no behaviour change

Comment: localhost did nothing either - tried changing in the use urls or where I'm browsing to or both - no change.  The thing I keep coming back to though - this code works perfectly, and is covered by _heaps_ of tests under windows.  I'm using exactly the same project, same ide under mac, and it's not working.

Comment: AND if I lose the "s" - ie use UseUrls( "http://*:"  + port) - and browse with http instead of https, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so for anyone who runs across this - I found I guess an answer:
you need to run in the terminal:

```
dotnet dev-certs https
```

which then asks you to run a really bizarre command:

```
sudo security set-key-partition-list -D localhost ...
```

which magically fixes things.